# substring pandas column between the same character

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have a pandas dataframe with the following column value:

```
data - test - data
```

I need to create the new column which includes string between '-'

```
test
```

I've tried:

```
df['column'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("-"):st.find("-")])
```

but it returns null (this is the same character and code treat it as the same character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` and take the first index in the list that is returned.

```py
df['column'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda s: s.split('-')[1].strip())
```